# Combine four integers into one

Tags: c, integer

I'm new to C and I'm trying to combine these four integers into one integer.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int intOne = 1+rand()%255;
int intTwo = 1+rand()%255;
int intThree = 1+rand()%255;
int intFour = 1+rand()%255;

int allCombined = ("%i.%i.%i.%i", intOne, intTwo, intThree, intFour);
printf("%i", allCombined);
```

All I need to do is combine these four integers into a single variable in IP address format.

Example: 108.41.239.216

How would I combine them and save them to a variable for later use?

Comment: Use plus + operator :)

Comment: `%i` in `printf` stands for "integer", not for "IP address". Integers do not have dots in their body.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I hope you're joking, right? Very funny :)

Comment: Use a string! You can't have those "."s in an integer

Comment: @ExpedientHF I suggest you get an idea about the fundamentals of C before trying to mess around with IP addresses and stuff. Currently you don't seem to know what you are even doing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I can't understand what OP wants, he is writing like python, either he need `sprintf()` function or bitwise operators. I just wanted to say OP that improve his question.

Comment: Do a `man -k inet_` on the shell's command line, then do `man xyz` for each of the results listed. Then read.

Answer (score 1):

**There are many ways to do this and no one way is right**. The natural solution that came to me (under the context of your snippet of code) is to store them in an array of integers of length 4. Then you can format them respectively. For example:

```
int ip_address[ 4 ] = { intOne, intTwo, intThree, intFour };
```

... and then when ever you want to use it it would be as follows:

```
printf( "%d.%d.%d.%d", ip_address[ 0 ], ip_address[ 1 ], ip_address[ 2 ], ip_address[ 3 ] );
```

... this would also give you an advantage if you ever needed to access parts of the IP address, you could do this in O(1).

Comment: Thank you, sorry for being such a C noob.

Comment: @ExpedientHF, everyone has started from your position it's ok. I am glad that the answer was able to push you in the right direction -- be sure to communicate this to others who have the same question as you by selecting the most appropriate answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways you could combine them:

1. Save all four bytes in an unsigned 32-bit integer.  First byte goes in bits 0 to 7, second byte goes in bits 8 to 15, etc.
2. Create a `struct` that contains the four values.  Then you can refer to them as `ipAddress.firstOctet`, `ipAddress.secondOctet`, etc.
3. Create an array of four bytes:  `ipAddress[0]`, `ipAddress[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL ));
  int intOne = 1 + rand() % 255;
  int intTwo = 1 + rand() % 255;
  int intThree = 1 + rand() % 255;
  int intFour = 1 + rand() % 255;

  {
    struct in_addr ia = { 
      (intOne << 0) + (intTwo << 8) + (intThree << 16) + (intFour << 24) /* Here you initialise the integer. */
    };

    printf("0x%x", ntohl(ai.s_addr)); /* Convert the integer to the correct byte order (endianness) and print it. */
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(ia)); /* Here you get the dotted version. */
  }

  return 0;
}
```